# Symmetric Operator with Different dot products

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, operator-theory

If I have a symmetric operator $A$ in a metric space $\mathscr{M}$.

Then $\langle Au,v\rangle =\langle v,Au\rangle $ with the dot product defined in $\mathscr{M}$.
My question is, if I keep the same vector space (in particular $\mathscr{M}$ is also a vector space), but I define another dot product in the same vector space $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_2$, then is it true that $A$ is still a symmetric operator in general?

Does it depend on $\mathscr{M}$ being a space of finite or infinite dimension or not?

My line of thoughts goes as follows:

**Option A:** Yes is true because even if we change the dot product, the vector space is the same and $A$ will keep on being symmetric.

**Option B:** False, because if we change the dot product, even if the vector space is the same, the metric space is not. So $A$ maybe is not symmetric.

Thanks pals.

Comment: What do you mean by dot product in a metric space? Dot products are only for vector spaces as far as I know.

Comment: A vector space does not require to have a dot product, just multiplication by scalars. A metric space is a vector space with a dot product, which means a way to measure space.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take your vector space to be $\mathbb{C}^2$ and pick $A$ to be represented by a Hermitian $2 \times 2$ matrix. Then $A$ is symmetric with respect to the standard dot product. Now pick a new inner product and try seeing if $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: well yes, but could you give an explanation as why? I can't see which of my to reasoning arguments if right, if any.

Comment: Well, $A$ is symmetric in the first inner product if $\langle Ax, y \rangle_1 = \langle x, Ay \rangle_1$. But how does this relate to the second inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_2$? There's no reason why this tells us anything about $\langle Ax, y \rangle_2$.

Comment: Ok thanks, so symmetry is not a property of the vector space by itself. You need a superior structure to make it happen.